# PowerShell cannot recognize zcat

Tags: powershell, command

I'm using zcat in PowerShell to check the info of the file.

```
zcat \Localizer\derivatives\\fmriprep\sub-S01\\func\sub-S01_task-localizer_space-MNI152NLin2009cAsym_boldref.nii.gz | head -c 1024 > trunc.nii
```

However, it indicates that The term 'zcat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program.
I know that zcat is a command in UNIX but I wanna use that in Wins, since it's a small step in my debugging process and I don't wanna change the system:( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for?
[PowerShell Gallery
| Get-GzipContent](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Get-GzipContent/)

"Gets the content of the gzip archive at the specified location."